# Why is my react app showing a blank page?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

I don't know where everything went wrong but at some point, my react app started showing only a blank screen. I've look into some tuto and afterward, I've realize that when I run the command  `npm run build`, I get the following error :

Failed to compile.

The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's not possible to use external type 'module' within a script

Comment: [Have you tried looking the error up?](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=The+target+environment+doesn%27t+support+dynamic+import%28%29+syntax+so+it%27s+not+possible+to+use+external+type+%27module%27+within+a+script&cat=web&pl=ext-ff&language=english&extVersion=1.3.0)

Comment: yes I did, most of the thing that I tried did nothing or weren't about the same problem

Comment: Is this error occurring with your React client, or your node server?

Comment: pretty sur it's my react client